# Doubt in the solution of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know that the solution to the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dt}=y(a-by), a>0, b>0, y(0)=y_0$ can be derived using integration using partial fractions, and the final result is: $$y=a/(b+ke^{-at})$$ where $k$ is $(a/y_0)-b$.

My doubt is: Say $y_0<0$. Then the differential equation itself tells me that $\frac{dy}{dt}<0$ and hence $y$ would just go on falling as $t$ increases, and it would always remain negative. But if you look at the behaviour of the function $y$, there would be a vertical asymptote at some positive value of $t$ (to be precise, where $b+ke^{-at}=0$. Beyond this value of $t$, $y$ would be positive. What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: Just a sidenote: You also have two constant solutions y=0 and y=a/b.

Comment: $y=a/b$ I obtain if I put $y_0=a/b$. Although I can see how $y=0$ is a solution, why am I not obtaining it as a specific case of the general solution that I found using integration?

Comment: You get $y=0$ for $k=\infty$, or after a re-parametrization of the constant $k=c/d$, $y=ad/(bd+ce^{-at})$ for $(c,d)=(1,0)$. (One could impose $c^2+d^2=1$ or $\max(|c|,|d|)=1$ to get back to a one-dimensional parameter set.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got nothing wrong, it is just that the solution ends at the asymptote. Solutions of differential equations are defined over intervals containing the initial point. These intervals can have finite end points even for the so-called "maximal solution". Often these finite end points happen because the trajectory of the solution moves to infinity in finite time, as happens here.

Comment: Well..ok. I would have to go in depth to understand what this means, but good to know I wasn't getting it wrong.

Comment: Basically your answer comes with a specific domain. As you noted the function $y=a/(b+ke^{-at}$ does have an asymptote and as such has two distinct sections to its domain. Your initial value ($y(0)=y_0$) specifics which half of the domain you should use (the half including $t=0$).

Comment: Right, got it. Thanks.

Comment: @bitter-sweet In differential equations, you have functions defined by formulas whose domain isn't the maximal domain of that formula. You've seen something similar before in calculus: $f(x)=\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$ can be given with the formula $x+2$, but $x+2$ is defined for all real numbers while $f$ itself is not defined at $x=2$.

Comment: @Ian Got it. But in general for other differential equations how would I know which domain to consider? In this case I ignore the region beyond the asymptote because it is clearly creating the problem I mentioned in my original question, is it?

Comment: @bitter-sweet In terms of doing problems, you find the solution just in terms of a formula, and then you restrict the domain to the largest open interval containing the initial point on which the formula you wrote down defines a continuous function. There is a more general way of expressing this that doesn't depend on obtaining an explicit formula, but this will get you through problems like the one in the OP.

Comment: @Ian Ok great, it's totally clear now.

Answer (score 0):

It is a classical differential equation called the **logistic differential equation** http://math.usu.edu/~powell/biomath/mlab3-02/node2.html